# How to draw 2D texture from 3D texture

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-3

I have a 2D game, and I want to use a 3D texture for fog to make it animated .... however, I don't want the entire 3D texture to be shown, I just want the part of the texture that's at Z 0.

How do I do this?

Comment: what is a 3D texture? (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:3D_Textures It's basically a bunch of 2D textures, blended together ... reason why I want it is because it smoothly blends the textures together, which would be harder to do otherwise.

Comment: This is a common use case for 3D textures, thus there should be plenty of resources across the internet. To give further help, we would need to know what version of OpenGL you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3D textures work analogously to 2D ones. You initialize the texture using `glTexImage3D()`, bind it to a `sampler3D`, and access it in the fragment shader using `texture()`.

```
//fog.frag
uniform sampler3D fog;
uniform float z;

in vec2 texCoord;

void main(){
    vec4 color = texture(fog, vec3(texCoord, z));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you use the texture coordinates to access the texture, so you can use the thrid component to select the "layer".

I don't know what OpenGL version you are targeting. For really old versions and using the fixed-function pipleline, you can just enable the 3D texuring as you did with the 2D texturing, and can use the *texture matrix*  (`glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE)`) yo add some transformation along the z axis. That way, you can work with 2D texcoords as before, and can simply select the layer by modifying said matrix.

However, I strongly recommend that you don't use 3D texures for that use case, but *2D array textures*. However, to do so, you must use shaders, and selecting the layer of the texture via the shader is really easy to do.

Comment: Well I am using OpenGL 3 ... but the reason why I want a 3D texture is for the blending of the textures ... is there any way to do that with a 2D array texture?

Comment: Well, if you ewant to blend between the layers, 3D textures are the way to go.